# Proper way to traverse the angular.element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, traversal, jqlite

I'm using a directive where I got the DOM element in the link function of it, and there I have the an element which I want to access.

i.e.

```
// element = <directive>
//             ...
//             <div id="target"></div>
//             ...
//           </directive>
```

If I want to get the element, for example to do a `.click()` event, I'd need to use the '`document`' object, cause I haven't found a way to go directly to this `#target` element at once.

Any idea on the proper way to do this ?
Unfortunately jqLite only gives us a `find()` function where you can't search by `id` not `class`

Comment: did u try angular.element(elem.querySelector('.classname'))

Comment: that's better that what I was using haha thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Personally, when I use angularjs, I wrap everything in a new reference that automatically uses querySelectorAll for targeting the DOM, like so:

```
YOUR_APP.run(function() {
    jqLite = function(selector) {
        var selectorResult = (typeof selector == 'object') ? selector : document.querySelectorAll(selector)
        return angular.element(selectorResult)
    }; 
})
```

So I can use it "like jQuery", using: `jqLite('body > div').addClass('whatever');`

There are rare situations where this wouldn't behave like jQuery, for example, by using querySelectorAll, you no longer get an array of objects with the results, like jQuery would have done, but a nodeList, so you cannot apply the forEach method for example, but there are easy workarounds.
And whenever the new reference jqLite can't do the job, you can always use angular.element directly.

But this should satisfy 99% of most jQuery needs :)

Hope this helps.